# Is there any plugin for Visual Studio to highlight and auto-complete ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, autocomplete

So far tried some but none did auto-complete and the syntax highlighting was very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
scripts/_references.js with one line like:
/// <reference path="../ext/ext-all-debug.js" />
```

I don´t think there is a plugin for vs, or you can use sencha arquitect, the new version include autocomplete, but it´s not free, you have to pay for the license